# dataframe.head() throws TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [True] of <class 'bool'>

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I get the following error whenever I try to execute the head() command.

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [True] of <class 'bool'>
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import os
```

Then I load the data from an excel file.

```
#load the data
dataset_dec = pd.read_excel('DataDecember_20201201_20201231.xlsx',sheet_name='Data')
```

The data gets loaded properly and I am able to check info.

```
dataset_dec.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1886 entries, 0 to 1885
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column                   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                   --------------  -----  
 0   Month                    1886 non-null   object 
 1   IMSI                     1886 non-null   int64  
 2   Sum Bytes upload         1886 non-null   object 
 3   Sum Bytes download       1886 non-null   object 
 4   Sum Total Kbytes         1886 non-null   object 
 5   Sum Bytes upload Test    1886 non-null   int64  
 6   Sum Bytes download Test  1886 non-null   int64  
 7   Sum Total KbytesTest     1886 non-null   float64
 8   Nr. of PS Sessions       1886 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(3), object(5)
memory usage: 132.7+ KB
```

But when I run `dataset_dec.head()` I get the following error

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [True] of <class 'bool'>
```

I checked the dtype of the index

```
dataset_dec.index.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

Also there is no issue when I use .iloc with a single index value

```
dataset_dec.iloc[4]
```

Ignore the IMSI value with 'xxxx' as I have manually truncated it.

```
Month                              2020-12
IMSI                       xxxxx25589xxxx
Sum Bytes upload                 2,084,590
Sum Bytes download               2,062,000
Sum Total Kbytes                  4,049.40
Sum Bytes upload Test                    0
Sum Bytes download Test                  0
Sum Total KbytesTest                     0
Nr. of PS Sessions                       6
Name: 4, dtype: object
```

But when used for a range of index, it fails and throws the same error

```
dataset_dec.iloc[4:10]
```

I am able to do all other operations except viewing the dataframe using the head command.

Comment: It looks like broken pandas, is possible reinstal? Or upgrade?

Comment: I tried to reinstall and had the same issue. Then I duplicated the code on a lab environment hosted on Cloud and it works fine over there. For my local install, I will try to fix this. Highly appreciate your suggestion.